# How could I create an Azure Storage Account size Alert

Tags: azure, storage

For example, if I wanted to get an alert or an email when my File Storage reaches 100GB. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you done *any* research on this?

Comment: Yes, and I continue to do so. My google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I was able to find an answer using Google search `azure storage account alerts`, giving me these Microsoft's documentations (2 out of 4 first results):*

According [Monitor a storage account in the Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account) we can

1. add monitoring (charts) of several metrics from 
   [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) **> Storage accounts > Diagnostics > Monitoring**.
2. configure metrics alerts for any metric with an alert *condition* and a *threshold* from

   - **Monitoring (classic) > Alerts (classic) > Add metric alert (classic)** or
   - **Monitoring > Alerts > New alert rule**.

According to [Azure Storage metrics in Azure Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-metrics-in-azure-monitor) there are metrics for:

- BlobCapacity: The total of Blob storage used in the storage account.
- TableCapacity: The amount of Table storage used by the storage account.
- QueueCapacity: The amount of Queue storage used by the storage account.
- FileCapacity: The amount of File storage used by the storage account.

The unit for each is bytes: for 100 GB the value would be 107374182400.

Comment: Thanks for that. For the ones that google this, you need to go to the Alerts (classic) and change the resource to the type of storage that you are monitoring.